# how to count row in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I've got data as picture below, i'm using crystal report to display statistic report from that data.

i want to count MRN which got 2 until 5 rows of episode number only.
currently im doing

1) group MRN in crystal report and count(episode number).

2) create 1 formula like : 
if count(episode number) >=2 and count(episode number)<=5 then count(episode number)"

3) put the formula to report and try to insert summary to count that formula, but no selection summary appear for that formula.

Can you give me an idea how to count MRN with 2 until 5 episode only? refer to picture for clear explanation

[image]

Comment: Sorry need to off now,, maybe tom can help you

Comment: other option to it, ,create separate query then import that query to your crystal raport,, if not then you can do this at cr formula..

Comment: Use something like  if(Next({MRN}) <> {MRN}) or Previous to write your count formula

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal you can use two condition types to sort which records are being showed:

1. Record selection formula
2. Group selection formula

Both are located in the menu *Report > Selection formulas*

In your case you can define a group on field *MRN* and create a Count field inside that group. To show only groups where the count is between 2 and 5, use the *Selection Formula > Group* condition in the Report menu.

```
Count ({EpisodeNo},{MRN}) <=5 and Count ({EpisodeNo},{MRN})>=2
```